# When DateTimePicker is on tab the lost focus not update the value

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, datetimepicker

I have a problem with `DateTimePicker`,
I put 3 `DateTimePicker` on `tab control` one for each `tabitem`.
Now i set time by

```
dateTimePicker1.Text="1:00";
dateTimePicker2.Text="2:00";
dateTimePicker3.Text="3:00";
```

In the first tab the `DateTimePicker` work fine by

```
MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Text); //Show "01:00"
```

but when i want to read `dateTimePicker2.Text` show me empty
but when i clicked on second tab thats work fine and show me "02:00"

whats my problem?

Comment: Who is the parent of `dateTimePicker1`? Which event you added these code? Which platform? Winforms, Wpf, Web?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel parent is TabControl and .net framework 3.5 and Winforms

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i added this code in a event of click button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U gonne have to preload your tabs as the controls on it are not initiated yet.

Something like this will work

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // Preload tabs
     tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage3;
     tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
     // Select tab 1
     tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
     // Set values
     dateTimePicker1.Text = "1:00";
     dateTimePicker2.Text = "2:00";
     dateTimePicker2.Text = "3:00";

 }
```

Even better u can use tabPage.show() for each tab u want to preload.

```
 // Preload tabs
 tabPage3.Show();
 tabPage2.Show();
 // Select tab 1
 tabPage1.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look at this page on *Object Lifetime Events*, specifically the *Loaded* section. I believe since the DatePicker is on the second tab that until it is visible and loaded it will not have the correct value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx